# AngularJS - $scope undefined within same controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller where I am trying to store information in $scope.weather and then use it's contents to pass to a function.  When I log the result of $scope.weather[0].latitude when I use it one function but when I call it another function within the same controller the result is coming back undefined.  Shouldn't the $scope be usable within the same controller?  This is also within the same function.

```
angular.module('CityCtrl', []).controller('CityController', ['$scope', '$http', 'City', function($scope,  $http,  City){

$scope.update = function (zip) {
    City.get({zip : zip}).success(function(response){
        $scope.weather = response
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.weather = response.data;

        // This is returning the expected result
        console.log($scope.weather[0].latitude;
    })

    if(zip.length === 5){

        // This is coming back undefined
        console.log($scope.weather[0].latitude);

        var box = getBoundingBox([$scope.weather[0].latitude, $scope.weather[0].longitude], 50);

        City.matches(box[1], box[3], box[0], box[2]).success(function(response){
            $scope.matches = response
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.matches = response.data;
            console.log($scope.matches);
        })

    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an order of operations issue.

When you `console.log($scope.weather[0].latitude)` in the if statement `$scope.weather` has not actually been set yet because the `City.get()` call is asynchronous. This means `$scope.weather` will not be set until a successful response is returned from the City service, which in your case will execute after the code block in the if statement.

In order for your if statement code to have access to `$scope.weather` you would need to include it in the `.then(function() { // if logic here }` portion of your code.

Also it is worth noting that `City.get().success()` and `City.get().then(successFunction)` are pretty much doing the same thing. You should use one or the other, but you shouldn't need to use both.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot more sense.